# Load Data InFile SQL statement is not allowed to be executed when creating MySQL Events

Tags: mysql

I know that the Load Data InFile SQL statement is not allowed to be executed when creating MySQL Events.
I am trying to find an alternative solution to this, but until now I cant.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Anyone has any idea if there is any other way that we can set to load external file into the tables on a scheduled basis?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you cant just do the Load Data into a temporary file of the expected input format?  Add a few extra columns such as for pre-processing flags if that might help?  Then that could be a single load without any other interactions of triggers and such.  Then you could have a stored procedure run query / fetch / process / insert, etc. based on the already loaded records into a table.  If you skip some, so be it, others process as normal?  Just something I have done in the past and might be an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

although I did not quite understand your question if you are on a Linux based system, you could create a simple bash script to load any external data into MySQL . Either dump it locally and load it or pull from external source and load it the same way you would load any file.

Answer (score 0):

For example as below I am trying to import my data from a csv file to my customers table and I want to schedule it every 5 minutes.
Hence I include the load data infile under a mysql event. Code as below
However, it returns an error: **ERROR Code 1314: LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedures.**

Any alternative way that i can import a csv file data into a table and execute it during a schedule of every 5 minutes?

```
    USE sales;
CREATE EVENT import_file_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
DO 
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Importfile.csv'
    INTO TABLE customers
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (@first_name,@last_name,@gender,@email_address,@number_of_complaints)
    SET first_name = NULLIF(@first_name,''),
        last_name = NULLIF(@last_name,''),
        gender = NULLIF(@gender,''),
        email_address = NULLIF(@email_address,'');
```